# Why is flash for Chromium (pepperflashplugin) not automatically updated?

Tags: apt, updates, flash, chromium

To update flash in Chromium-based browsers (Ubuntu 16.04) I have to run manually :

```
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

This will update the flash plugin for Chromium and Opera.

BTW there is also a bug in `update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree`:

```
update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --status
Flash Player version installed on this system  : 22.0.0.209
Flash Player version available on upstream site: 22.0.0.209
```

While the latest version is [`23.0.0.162`](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/), the only way to install that version is to remove it first, and reinstall it later:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove pepperflashplugin-nonfree
sudo apt install pepperflashplugin-nonfree

sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --status
Flash Player version installed on this system  : 23.0.0.162
Flash Player version available on upstream site: 22.0.0.209
```

So it's buggy, but more importantly, why isn't the update of this important internet plugin and (major weakness) not done (or hooked into) the general update process `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that both `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` and `flashplugin-installer` are [deprecated](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash//).

There is a new package `adobe-flashplugin` in the  `Canonical Partners software` section that will update both the Chromium and Firefox plugins.

You have to enable `Canonical Partners` source. It will mark the `flashplugin-installer` as **deprecated / to be removed**, but unfortunately not the `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`, you have to remove that yourself.

### Solution

Enable `Canonical Partners` in System settings -> Software and Updates -> tab `Other software`, then:

```
sudo apt remove pepperflashplugin-nonfree flashplugin-installer
sudo apt update
sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
```

First row will delete the old plugin:

```
/usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/libpepflashplayer.so
```

and last row will install the plugin in:

```
/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so
```

### Note

**You have to check that for Canonical Partners the distribution is set to xenial, this is not always done automatically for upgraded systems.**

Otherwise it will install older versions of the adobe-flashplugin package:
It should install adobe-flashplugin version:

```
 1:20160913.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
```

On upgrade installations 14.04 -> 16.04 it installs `1:20160913.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1`, which offers an updated flash but on upgraded older installations (from 13.10->...->16.04) it offers an outdated package, that does **not** install the pepperplugin. Hence Opera uses the Chrome location, Chromium does not.

So don't forget to set the distribution to `xenial` for Canonical Partners, then it will offer the 16.04 package.

At last check this [Adobe page](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/) to verify your version.

(Apparently this doesn't work for the Yandex browser.)

Comment: Just to be clear you just stick "rm " in front of the old .so file to be removed and nothing else?

Comment: No,  `sudo apt remove pepperflashplugin-nonfree` will do

Comment: from my understanding, the new `adobe-flashplugin` package contains the old NPAPI plugin, updated to latest. It is only for **firefox** and not for chrome.

Comment: @solsTiCe: It contains both the NPAPI and PPAPI plugins. Hence it's both for Firefox and Chromium (Chrome doesn't need a plugin, since it's shipped with Flash).

Comment: @solsTiCe give it a try, it does both, and also Opera.

Comment: yeah. you can purge instead of removing to delete the plugin.. Also it is installed in /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so. Its strange tough that chromium report it as version 11.2.999.999 in chrome://plugins

Comment: Your latest edit is confusing. While it's advisable to enable Canonical Partner for xenial if you are on 16.04, it doesn't really matter much in this case. `1:20160913.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1` is (basically) the same package as `1:20160913.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`, and they both install both PPAPI and NPAPI plugins.

Comment: Agreed, but 14.04 is not future-proof, and you need to set it on an even upgraded older systems like raring. I'm just explaining what happened on different systems I use.

Comment: @solsTiCe. Chromium does report the right version, if you check on the Adobe page, but I agree it is  a confusing version  that Chromium reports internally. Opera reports the `Version: 23.0.0.162` for the same plugin.